# browser-sync is not reloading my browser after making changes to the html

Tags: javascript

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
    const sass = require('gulp-sass');
    const nunjucks = require('gulp-nunjucks');
    const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
    const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
    const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
    const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
    const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

    var config = {
        bootstrapDir: './node_modules/bootstrap-sass',
        uploadDir: './upload'
    };

    gulp.task('css', function () {
        gulp.src('./css/*')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.uploadDir + '/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
    });

    gulp.task('fonts', function () {
        gulp.src(config.bootstrapDir + '/assets/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.uploadDir + '/fonts'));
    });

    gulp.task('js', function () {
        gulp.src('./js/*')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.uploadDir + '/js'));
    });

    gulp.task('images', function () {
        gulp.src('./images/**/*')
            .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.uploadDir + '/images'));
    });
// This is the code for the template(html) task
    gulp.task('templates', function () {
        gulp.src('./templates/*.html')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(nunjucks.compile({
            appName: 'Gulp' //Global variable
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.uploadDir));
    });

    gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
        browserSync.init({
            server: {
                baseDir: config.uploadDir
            }
        });
    });

//This is my watch task
    gulp.task('watch',['browserSync', 'css', 'templates'], function() {
        gulp.watch('./css/*', ['css']);
        gulp.watch('./templates/*.html', ['templates', browserSync.reload]);
    })

    //gulp.task('default', ['css', 'fonts', 'js', 'images', 'templates', 'browserSync']);
    enter code here
```

When i run gulp watch any changes made to the css files causes the browser to reload , but if i make a change to my html file, i will need to refresh the browser before i can see the changes

I get to see the changes in my uploadDir "(./upload)" folder but can;t figure out why i have to refresh the page to see the changes live

Comment: With `gulp.watch('./templates/*.html', ['templates', browserSync.reload])` you're calling your template task in parallel with a reload from browserSync. Probably the browser reloads before your html files have finished compiling, meaning the same old files will be reloaded.
Try removing `browserSync.reload` from your watch task, and instead append your template task with `.on('end', browserSync.reload);`. Don't forget to remove the semicolon from the previous line.